# Azure DevOps: Analytics - Tests in pipeline - how to remove hooks: afterEach() from test failure report?

Tags: azure, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, cypress

Hooks are included in the failed test results, the number of failures is overstated because of afterEach() hooks. I would like the number of failed tests to reflect the actual number of tests, without the afterEach () hooks.

[image]

I moved the afterEach() hooks from each tests to the cypress support file, but the display of the failure tests is the same - it displays test failure and, in addition, afterEach() failure.
I'd like to remove the afterEach() entries from the test report results and not show them in the results.
Is it possible? How can I configure it?

Comment: What about using after() instead of afterEach()? It will only run once.

Comment: Changing afterEach() to after() will make the failed test results simply less, but I would like to configure globally so that hooks do not appear in the Junit test results - this applies to afterEach() but also after() and before().